# echo json_encode ($data) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to echo an array to ajax request by echoing it with this syntax (server side)

```
 echo json_encode($a);
```

In my client side I have this function:

```
$.ajax({
            url:'loaddata.php',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

but nothing happens. Where is the problem? Why `json_encode()` doesn't work?

Comment: Because you're using AJAX you will have to look for the result in the data returned to the function.

Comment: Check the Network tab of the browser console to see everything that's being returned.

Comment: Here is what you want to look after to make sure "it's working.":
- make sure `$a` is an array, `json_encode()` accepts `array`.
- instead of using `alert()`, use `console.log(data)` and track the output using dev tools, console log tab

Comment: ... Or you can just ckech your response in Brownser's Dev Tool  to see any kind of error...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that *"nothing happens"* and your `$.ajax` is lacking `error` handler, I think your PHP code outputs some fatal errors; thus, AJAX doesn't trigger anything.

Here is what you want to look after

#### PHP

- Add `header('Content-Type: Application/json')` to your file for `success` callback to parse the response as `JSON`.
- make sure `$a` is an array, `json_encode()` accepts `array`.

#### JavaScript

Add `error` handler to your `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'loaddata.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('something went wrong');
  }
});
```

Instead of using `alert()`, use `console.log(data)` and track the output using dev tools, network tab (recommended), or console log tab.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you are encoding is an array as commenters have stated, you also need to set

```
$a = array("key" => "value");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($a);
```

in the PHP script.

Answer (score -1):

There's not enough information here to nail down the problem for certain, but if nothing is happening at all then it could be that loaddata.php doesn't exist. Are you sure the file exists in the correct location and is named correctly?

Another possibility is that the $a variable in the PHP code has an empty value.

Have you verified that the ajax call works by altering a string? Something like alter('test')? If that shows then the ajax url should be fine then the problem would be on the PHP side.

Comment: Please do not use an answer to clarify a question.